# Why currentUser is null after login? React Native Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm learning to use Redux to fetch user's info in React Native but `currentUser is null` error keeps popping up, I think I set things up properly though. Can someone help me in that?

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 function Profile(props) {
        const { currentUser } = props;
        console.log({currentUser})  
    
       return (
         <View>
         <Text>{currentUser.name}</Text>
         </View>
               );
     }


    const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  
     })
     export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

And here's how I dispatch data using Redux:

```
export function fetchUser() {
    return ((dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists) {
                    dispatch({ type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data() })
                }
                else {
                    console.log('does not exist')
                }
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is caused because you are trying to render the `Profile` component even when `currentUser` would be `null` which would fail because you can't access a property off of `null`.  This can be controlled within the `Profile` component:

```js
export default function Profile(props) {
  const { currentUser } = props;

  if (!currentUser) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading user...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{currentUser.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```